# Windows 7 Can't Connect to Network Drive on Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, network-drive

I have a Windows XP desktop and a Windows 7 laptop both connected to a TrendNET TEW-432BRP router, which is connected to the Internet. They both have static IPs. The desktop has an external hard drive connected to it. The laptop is wireless and the desktop is wired.

I enabled sharing on the external hard drive about two years ago when I bought it. I mapped it as a network drive on the laptop. I think it was yesterday, the laptop just stopped recognizing any of the computers on my network (When I open network, my laptop's the only one on it). I also get an error message "An error occurred while connecting A: to \CERTIFIED-DATA\Expansion Microsoft Windows Network: The network path was not found. The connection has not been restored" when I try to connect to the network drive.

Both computers run Avast, and there hasn't been any problems with it.

This has happened before but I never figured out why and how to fix it. It's usually fixed when I reinstall the OS of the affected system.

**Update:**

I can't navigate the computer using `\\CERTIFIED-DATA`. I get a message saying "Windows cannot access \CERTIFIED-DATA. Check the spelling of the name, Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network"

I clicked diagnose on the message and it failed to find anything wrong

I clicked diagnose on my wireless connection, and it just keeps trying to check if something is wrong with the connection

I can ping it successfully

**Update 2:** I can see the computers on my network, but I still get the same message when I click on them

Comment: When this happens, can you navigate to the share via UNC path?  Does the machine respond to Ping?  What have you tried already?

Comment: @techie007 Sorry, it's added now

Comment: Is the Certified-Data machine on and not asleep?  If you reboot either/both of the machines, does it start working again?

Comment: It's on, and I tried rebooting them both. It hasn't worked since yesterday. Or maybe it was the day before, but it was very recent

Comment: can you navigate to it's IP address? e.g. `\\192.168.0.10`

Comment: @SeanCheshire Nope. I can ping their IPs but I can't reach them by Explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the service `TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper` needs to be enabled

Answer (score 1):

Verify that "Client for Microsoft Networks" is enabled on your Network Connection.

Start-> Settings -> Network Connections

*Right Click* your "Local Area connection"

*Click* properties

Verify that "Client for Microsoft Networks" is Checked

Comment: It's enabled on all of the connections